# Data structure for indirect symmetrical synonym

Tags: ruby, synonym, symmetric, thesaurus

I have a set of synonyms for example like this:

big large
large huge
small little
apple banana

Meaning big is a synonym for large, large is synonym for huge, small for little, apple for banana and vice versa(large is synonym for big, etc). Another thing is "big" is a synonym for "huge" and "huge" is a synonym for "big" because of indirect relationship via "large".

This should be something like thesaurus? But I'm not sure how the data structure should look.

Comment: Possibly an undirected graph, with words as vertices and edges symbolizing a "synonym" relationship

Comment: ye disconnected graph might be a solution for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option would be an array of arrays like:

```
[
  ['big', 'large', 'huge'],
  ['small', 'little']
]
```

Alternately if e.g. huge is not a synonym of big in your model then you might want a hash like:

```
{
  big: ['large'],
  large: ['big', 'huge'],
  huge: ['large'],
  small: ['little', 'tiny'],
  little: ['small'],
  ...
}
```

It really depends on what you plan do do with it.

Comment: Ye I tried doing the first solution, which is the correct one. But doing a union between them is giving me some problems. I end up with something like:
```[
  ['big', 'large', 'huge'],
  ['small', 'little'],
  ['something', 'huge'],
  ['something_else', 'large'],
]```

Comment: Problem is that the pair between some synonyms might be established later, based on 3rd or 4th synonym pair, so I would have to union existing arrays

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "doing a union" in this context

Comment: Yup, that is exactly what I did in the end. I got exactly that.

Comment: I needed to create a thesaurus and figure out if 2 words are synonyms. I created graph like this and then just used DFS to go over it.

Answer (score 1):

"Many different aspects of language have a natural representation as graphs. Graphs can also be used to describe how words relate to one another semantically. Within each word class, words are grouped into sets of synonyms, so-called synsets." - according [to this article](https://d-nb.info/983808635/34).

So, for an example synset for word '*banana*' is *(elongated crescent-shaped **yellow** **fruit** with soft **sweet** **flesh**)* according to [WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=banana&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=00). Synsets are linked to one another by semantic relationships. So, you can find simmilar semantic synset for word '*apple*' *(**fruit** with red or **yellow** or green skin and **sweet** to tart crisp whitish **flesh**)*.

You can use [this ruby gem](https://github.com/doches/rwordnet) to build a graph using WordNet database.

Comment: This was a very simple graph with dfs in the end. It was quite simple solution.